# How to add text at the end of Arc

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

Please find below my code for creating the arc, i would like to append text within a circle at the end of arc(ie end  angle)

```js
var svgContainer = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .append("svg:svg")
  .attr("width", 350)
  .attr("height", 350)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(50, 50)");

var outerRadius = 40;
var stroke = 5;

var outerArc = d3.arc()
  .innerRadius(outerRadius)
  .outerRadius(outerRadius)
  .startAngle(0)
  .endAngle(5);

svgContainer.append("path")
  .style("fill", "none")
  .style("stroke", "#0B9B29")
  .style("stroke-width", stroke)
  .attr('stroke-linejoin', 'round')
  .attr("d", outerArc());
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

for example

[image]

Comment: don't have the time at the moment to write you out the code, but I learned it from this site: https://www.visualcinnamon.com/2015/09/placing-text-on-arcs.html hope it helps you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without dealing with the arc generator itself, an easy way to get the end point of the arc is using [getPointAtLength](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGPathElement/getPointAtLength):

```
var point = path.node().getPointAtLength(path.node().getTotalLength() / 2);
```

Pay attention to the division by 2: this is necessary because the arc goes to the end angle and then back to the start.

Then, just use the `x` and `y` properties of that point to draw the circle and the text.

Here is your code with those changes:

```js
var svgContainer = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .append("svg:svg")
  .attr("width", 350)
  .attr("height", 350)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(50, 50)");

var outerRadius = 40;
var stroke = 5;

var outerArc = d3.arc()
  .innerRadius(outerRadius)
  .outerRadius(outerRadius)
  .startAngle(0)
  .endAngle(5);

var path = svgContainer.append("path")
  .style("fill", "none")
  .style("stroke", "#0B9B29")
  .style("stroke-width", stroke)
  .attr('stroke-linejoin', 'round')
  .attr("d", outerArc());

var point = path.node().getPointAtLength(path.node().getTotalLength() / 2);

var circle = svgContainer.append("circle")
  .attr("fill", "#0B9B29")
  .attr("cx", point.x)
  .attr("cy", point.y)
  .attr("r", 10);

var text = svgContainer.append("text")
  .attr("fill", "white")
  .attr("x", point.x)
  .attr("y", point.y)
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .attr("dominant-baseline", "central")
  .attr("font-size", "8px")
  .text(d3.format(".0%")(5 / (Math.PI * 2)));
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Wow, you made my day!

Comment: Thanks Gerardo !!! You also made my day :) Simple and elegant solution!